# Show that $|f |\colon A \to \mathbb R$ defined by $| f | = |f(x)|$ is continuous at $a$

Tags: continuity

Let $f\colon A \to \mathbb R$ be continuous at $a\in A$. Show that $| f |\colon A \to \mathbb R$ defined by $| f |(x) = | f(x)|$ is continuous at $a$.

Given $\epsilon > 0$. And for all $\epsilon > 0$ there exists $\gamma > 0$.
I know that since $f\colon A \to \mathbb R$ is continuous at $a\in A$ then
it follows that $\mid x - a\mid < \gamma$ and $\mid f(x) - f(a) \mid  < \epsilon$

$\mid f(x) - f(a)  \mid  = \mid 2f(x) - f(a) - f(x) \mid = \mid 2f(x)\mid - \mid f(a) + f(x)\mid$

Ok guys, after bashing my head I realised that I over complicated the whole thing and noticed what to do. You can ignore my reasoning above.

Since $f$ is continuous at $a$ all $\epsilon > 0$ and there exists $\gamma > 0$ such that $ x \in A$

This is what I really missed:

$\mid \mid f(x) \mid - \mid f(a) \mid \mid \le \mid f(x) - f(a) \mid  $

so

$\mid \mid f(x) \mid - \mid f(a) \mid \mid \le \mid f(x) - f(a) \mid \lt \epsilon $

hence

$\mid \mid f(x) \mid - \mid f(a) \mid \mid \lt \epsilon $

therefore $\mid f \mid$ is continuous at $a$ also.

Took forever but the questions did help me. Always surprising to see how simple it really is. Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to MSE! What is your definition of continuity?

Comment: Thank you! Sorry if this sounds a bit rushed as I have a programming class in 20 minutes.

For all $\epsilon > 0 $ there exists $\omega > 0$ s.t. $\mid x-a \mid < \omega \implies \mid f(x) - f(a) \mid < \epsilon$

Comment: Other than the range, are there any restrictions on $f$? For example, do you know that $f$ is continuous at $a$? Without such a restriction, your statement is false.

Comment: Yes yes. Your question made me realise that I made a mistake when I wrote the question. Edited the first part of the question "Let $f\colon A \to \mathbb R$ be continuous at $a\in A$"

Comment: Shouldn't there be some clarification as to what $A$ is?

Comment: Believe it or not the top paragraph is the entire question. I'm thinking that I have to use the inequality involving epsilon and somehow isolate $\mid f(x) \mid$ (which is what I have done on the 3rd paragraph. I'm trying to progress by finding an equivalent that's equal or smaller than $ \mid f(x) + f(a) \mid $ and also connected to one of the inequalities. But this is a 2 mark question so I might be over complicating it.